# Instance attributes are lost in python process

Tags: python

I discovered a very strange behavior running an application built on python 2.6.
The problem has a random nature as it happened only ~3 times for the last 4 years across hundreds of servers running the same code.

Here is a sample code fragment which illustrates the behavior:

```
class Foo(object):
    pizza = "Not a real pizza"

    def __init__(self):
        self.pizza = "real pizza"
        self.bar = "some bar"

    def get_pizza(self):
        return self.pizza

    def get_bar(self):
        return self.bar


foo = Foo()

# Shows "real pizza" under normal conditions
# For the faulty process it returns "Not a real pizza"
print(foo.get_pizza())

# Shows "some bar" under normal conditions
# For the faulty process it throws an exception:
# AttributeError: 'Foo' object has no attribute 'bar'
print(foo.get_bar())
```

So, all instance variables are magically gone and static/class variables are still present.
I am unable to replicate this problem consistently.

Update: Just to make it clear, I do not think the code above is faulty. It has to be some external process, like GC or memory error which corrupts it. I am looking for a possible cause of this as well as for ideas how to identify this state. I can handle this for a singe class, but adding it to thousands of classes and tens of thousands of possible entry points around the project is problematic. Also standard/third party lib objects can be corrupted too.

Comment: I could not reproduce the problem using Python 2.7 and Python 3.6. Does it occur for you only using Python 2.6?

Comment: That application can only be ran in Python 2.x. Also the code sample above is just an illustration of what happens on very rare occasions  (once-twice a year). I was not able to replicate that behavior on a dev environment. Other processes running the same code on the same machine are fine and the problem is gone after restarting the faulty  process. I guess it could be the garbage collector incorrectly cleaning some objects.

Comment: If this really happens even in very rare cases, that would cause thousands of applications to crash. This will be hard to reconstruct and analyze. Is there something else that could fail? You could run your simple code above and run it all day long to analyze. On the other hand Python 2.x is not supported anymore ...

Comment: The only way this could happen is if somehow the `__init__` method doesn't run for those objects. That would be an extremely serious bug that wouldn't likely last for long.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to do it with python, but I am excluding this possibility. All 3 or 4 times it happened, broken classes were different - whatever was in memory at the time when some event occurred. Sometimes it happens even to objects from a standard library, like " 'GeneratorContextManager' object has no attribute 'gen'" (it is one of errors from yesterday).

Comment: @Rennnyyy Yes, it happens is extremely rare cases - the application is running of hundreds of servers 24/365 for years and it has appeared only a couple of times, every time on different classes. It could be some very specific set of factors, like antivirus software, memory errors, some system libs, third party libs or a combination of multiple factors. So there is a very low chance of replicating it by running the code above in a loop. The reason I posted the question here is to see if anyone had a similar expirience and if there was any pattern in this issue occurrences.

Comment: THis should be virtually impossible.
What I could imagine though:
Is this an application with threading?
If yes, then this could be a race condition of accessing an object  while it is being modified.

Any object that is written by one thread and read by another one might be read the wrong way.

You have to use `threading.Lock` for any read / modify to objects shared between two threads.

Comment: You should see whether you can upgrade at least to the most recent python 2.7 version.
I had strange bugs, that just disappeared when going to a newer version.

Comment: Thank you @gelonida. I agree this version of Python is very old and it is not being used in new applications we built. However, we have a technical limitation with a 3rd party API available only on 2.6 in this part of the app, so we need to live with this for a while. 

This application is multi-threaded and I suspect it could add to the problem. Though when it happens, it looks like all objects in memory are broken, not just one (including those which are protected with Lock).

Comment: so back to my other comment. Is threading being used in the code?

Comment: Also I don't really know that 3rd party API, but why is it not working with python2.7?
Do you have the source code? Is this a pip module? Is it a proprietary API?
If you can get the hands on the source. I'd be curious whether it wouldn't be rather easy to apply a few minor changes and make it work with py2.7

Do you have at least the most recent version of python 2.6 installed?

Comment: @gelonida just edited my comment above with multithreading information.

Comment: @gelonida We don’t have access to source code (those are pyd files compiled from c code as python extensions) and due to technical and copyright issues we cannot use anything but 2.6 to access them. Legacy :( In any way I appreciate your willing to help.

Comment: This is a bad situation. How performance critical is this API and what does it roughly do?
Could you create the smallest possible python 2.6 application that is providing this API as a service (HTTP/ REST/ SOCKET/.../named pipes/subprocess) and code all the rest of the application with a more modern python? This is not for free, but if you can, it might be good to isolate your 'legacy code' as much as you can from the rest of your code base.

Comment: @gelonida Great suggestion considering you are not familiar with the system. We are working on those projects. All new pieces of the systems are built using up-to-day tools and technologies and the old part is accessed via REST/MQ. It will just take some time to completely get rid of those relicts, as the system is quite big and complicated. I think my best hope is just to decommission it before the described problem becomes really critical.